# Validation Not Firing On TextBox

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-validators

So, basically I have multiple `TextBox`es on my page and some of them have validations with `RequiredFieldValidator`.
I am using `OnTextChanged` event on `txtMobileNo` TextBox Field to fetch the data from database.
If the number exists in the database the the rest of my `TextBox`es filled from server side.

Now, I am facing here a problem: my `MobileNo` Text Field skips the `RegularExpressionValidator` validation even if it is wrong.
I want to redirect to server side only if my number matches the validation logic.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <asp:Label ID="lblfortxtMobileNo" runat="server" Text="Mobile No"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtMobileNo_TextChanged" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfvtxtMobileNo" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtMobileNo" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
        ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
        runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Number"
        ControlToValidate="txtMobileNo"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{10})$"
    ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtName" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</div>
```

When I am set `CauseValidation = "true"` the result is somewhat what I want .
But it checks all the other `RequiredFieldValidator validation` as well before calling `OnTextChanged` function.
I just want to check Regular Expression Validation at this point for `txtMobileNo` and based on the result wants to display error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your wording because it was quite hard to follow and understand. If unintentionally I've changed the meaning please edit it.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank You For the Correction and edit is completely meant to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross check your regex id it is look like an duplicated id here.

Comment: Yes i have mismatched regex id's.